# how can I know which Ruby executable was used in ruby script?

Tags: ruby

there are two Ruby environments on a system, normal ruby and Chef embedded ruby. I want to know, in a ruby script, which ruby executable is used to invoke the script itself.  How can get that?

Comment: How do you run the script? Are you using `ruby script_name.rb` or `./script_name.rb` (with a shebang on the first line)?

Comment: Check out the [pre-defined global constants](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/doc/globals_rdoc.html#label-Pre-defined+global+constants) starting with `RUBY_`

Comment: couldn't find the full path of ruby in the pre-defined global constants. @Stefan

Comment: @3limin4t0r I'm writing a script for other people to use. I don't know which ruby env the user will use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Recommended Solutions

Use the poorly-documented RbConfig module, if available:

```
RbConfig.ruby
#=> "/Users/foo/.rubies/ruby-2.7.0/bin/ruby"
```

Alternatively, you can use the easier-to-find [Gem module](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/Gem.html#method-c-ruby) from the standard library to do the same thing:

```
Gem.ruby
#=> "/Users/foo/.rubies/ruby-2.7.0/bin/ruby"
```

### Other Approaches

The RbConfig and Gem modules are your best bet, but there may be times when you need to get at the version or path information another way. Here are some different approaches.

#### Get the Version

You can return the version of the executing Ruby as a String with:

```
RUBY_VERSION
#=> "2.7.0"
```

#### Get the Path

Ruby is usually installed to `bin/ruby` in the *RUBY_ROOT*. You can return the expected path to the running Ruby binary (and verify it actually exists, if necessary) as follows:

```
ENV["RUBY_ROOT"] + "/bin/ruby"
#=> "/Users/foo/.rubies/ruby-2.7.0/bin/ruby"

File.exist? ENV["RUBY_ROOT"] + "/bin/ruby"
#=> true
```

Alternatively, you can use [Kernel#`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-60) to find the first Ruby in your *PATH* as follows:

```
`which ruby`.chomp
=> "/Users/foo/.rubies/ruby-2.7.0/bin/ruby"
```

There are certainly edge cases where either approach can be misleading, though. For example, Ruby may have been built in a non-standard way, or you may have invoked Ruby with a fully-qualified path rather than calling the first binary in *PATH*. That makes "roll your own" lookups less reliable, but if your environment is missing the RbConfig or Gem modules for some reason, this might be a reasonable alternative for you.

Comment: RUBY_VERSION can tell me the version, but couldn't tell me which ruby is used. 
ENV["RUBY_ROOT"] does't work, cause I don't have a "RUBY_ROOT" env variable. 
Gem.ruby and RbConfig.ruby work.